# Send mail using Laravel and gmail

Tags: php, laravel, gmail

I'm trying to send a mail using Laravel and Gmail account. I've changed .env and mail.php files several times trying stackoverflow solutions, but I get different errors. I don't know if it's important, but I'm trying this locally.
And with my actual configuration I get this exception:

```
[2022-07-22 11:01:16] local.ERROR: Process could not be started [El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
] {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 0): Process could not be started [El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
] at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\StreamBuffer.php:294)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\StreamBuffer.php(54): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->establishProcessConnection()
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(143): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(Array)
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\SendmailTransport.php(50): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start()
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Mailer.php(65): Swift_Transport_SendmailTransport->start()
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer.php(521): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message), Array)
#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer.php(288): Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer->sendSwiftMessage(Object(Swift_Message))
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailable.php(187): Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer->send(Object(Illuminate\\Support\\HtmlString), Array, Object(Closure))
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Traits\\Localizable.php(19): Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailable->Illuminate\\Mail\\{closure}()
#8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailable.php(188): Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailable->withLocale(NULL, Object(Closure))
#9 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer.php(304): Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailable->send(Object(Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer))
#10 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer.php(258): Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer->sendMailable(Object(App\\Mail\\CorreuAppComp))
#11 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\PendingMail.php(124): Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer->send(Object(App\\Mail\\CorreuAppComp))
#12 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\CorreusController.php(28): Illuminate\\Mail\\PendingMail->send(Object(App\\Mail\\CorreuAppComp))
#13 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php(54): App\\Http\\Controllers\\CorreusController->send(Object(App\\Models\\Comunitat))
#14 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('send', Array)
#15 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(262): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\CorreusController), 'send')
#16 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(205): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#17 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(721): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#18 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\inertiajs\\inertia-laravel\\src\\Middleware.php(82): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Inertia\\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#21 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate.php(44): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#25 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#26 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#27 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#29 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Session\\Store), Object(Closure))
#31 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(723): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#38 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(698): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#39 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(662): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#40 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(651): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#46 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#47 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#48 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#49 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#50 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#51 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#52 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#53 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\fruitcake\\laravel-cors\\src\\HandleCors.php(38): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#54 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#55 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#56 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#57 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#58 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(142): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#59 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(111): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#60 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\public\\index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#61 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ComApp\\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...')
#62 {main}
```

Mail.php

```
'mailers' => [
    'smtp' => [
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.google.com'),
        'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        'timeout' => null,
        'auth_mode' => null,
        'pretend' => false
    ],

    'ses' => [
        'transport' => 'ses',
    ],

    'mailgun' => [
        'transport' => 'mailgun',
    ],

    'postmark' => [
        'transport' => 'postmark',
    ],

    'sendmail' => [
        'transport' => 'sendmail',
        'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    ],

    'log' => [
        'transport' => 'log',
        'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
    ],

    'array' => [
        'transport' => 'array',
    ],
],

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'secret@gmail.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'secret'),
],

'reply_to' => ['address' => 'secret@gmail.com', 'name' => 'secret'],

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],
```

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.google.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=secret@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=secret
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=secret@gmail.com
```

MAIL_PASSWORD is an app password genereted in gmail.

I'm using a controller to send mail:

```
public function send(Comunitat $comunitat){
    Mail::to('secret@gmail.com')->send(new CorreuAppComp($comunitat));
    return Redirect::route('comunitats')->with('success', 'Correu enviat');

}
```

I've tried some solutions from stackoverflow but I get different errors.
Any help is welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Try to change your mailer from `smtp` to `sendmail`

Comment: Your MAIL_MAILER is set to sendmail, it should be smtp. It's trying to find the sendmail path on your system.

Comment: enabled two step authentication at gmail?

Comment: Yes, it's enabled

Comment: I've set MAIL_DRIVER=smtp, MAIL_MAILER=smtp and I get: Connection could not be established with host smtp.google.com :stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to tcp://smtp.google.com:587

Comment: Changing mailer to sendmail, I get: Process could not be started Exception. It's same exception from question.

Comment: try MAIL_PORT=465

Comment: and make sure you don't have any outbound firewall rules blocking it on your machine or on your router.

Comment: I've disabled both firewalls and changed port, but occurs the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Laravel 6, I am able to send mail with like this

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp 
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com 
MAIL_PORT=587 
MAIL_USERNAME=youruser@gmail.com 
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME=yourname
```

please notice that you use  "**smtp.google.com**" not "**smtp.gmail.com**",
also I think you must have  "**Enable POP for all mail**" at your gmail setting

Controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

    Mail::html($body, function ($message) use ($email_to) {
        $message
            ->to($email_to)
            ->subject($subject);
    });
```

mail.php

The default

**Please note** that i do not use an app password, but the account password becouse the gmail account I use, is deticated to the application.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed MAIL_HOST and MAIL_PORT and it's works.